# I set .bashrc but my promt looks still the same

Tags: linux, bash, styles, prompt, linux-mint

i'm quite new with linux and I want to tweak my terminal prompt. The default is user@user - Thinkpad- T420 ~$. That pretty annoying long. 
I searched google and I tried my best but it didn't show any difference.

What i have done:
echo $PS1

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\]
```

locate bashrc

```
    /etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/skel/#.bashrc#
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/etc/skel/.bashrc~
/usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc
/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/bash.bashrc
/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/skel/dot.bashrc
```

sudo -s Atom /directory

I changed in all files PS1="...." to PS1="hallo". Terminal prompt shows no difference.

Linux Kernel 
Mint
4.8.0-53-generic

greetings ! B

Comment: Have you sourced your `.bashrc`?

Comment: Hi PesaThe, i'm quite new with linux. What does it mean to "source" the .bashrc? Thank you for your fast answer either!

Comment: `source` is a builtin that does the following: *Read and execute commands from the filename argument in the current shell context*. So sourcing `~/.bashrc` executes all commands in your `.bashrc`, including your desired `PS1=something`. See [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) for more information.

Comment: Thank you PesaThe.Don't get me wrong but I could just type PS1=" hallo" in the terminal and it'll execute my demand and change the prompt. But how can i save changes?

Comment: That's why you need the special file, `.bashrc`. You put `PS1=something` to `~/.bashrc` and when you invoke new shell, your prompt will be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by editing the .bashrc file in my /home/myusername directory. Don't edit the files here /src/skel

Answer (score 2):

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Your terminal only reads the `.bashrc` on opening, or when you explicitly source it.

Comment: Hi Eric, does it matter where the .bashrc is located? I set the .bashrc in /etc/skel but nothing happens. Thank you for the fast answer.

Comment: @Bahamas `/etc/skel` is a special directory, don't put it there. Your best option is to define `PS1` in `.bashrc` located in your home directory: `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: If i type source bashrc the prompt changes to my test string. In a new terminal window it shows the old setting again.

Comment: I think it will work if you put it in your home directory.

Comment: The files in `/etc/skel` are only used to provide default files when creating a new user. They are ignored by (and indeed, are unknown to) `bash`.